# Cakephp pagination with join table field sort is not working

Tags: cakephp, sorting, join, pagination

Cakephp pagination with join table sort is not working for join table fields. But for custom sql  join query working fine. Please help me to come out.

See below sample code.. I have Artist.name join table field in order.

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'id', 
            'Song.title',
            'Song.date',
            'Artist.id AS artist_id',
            'Artist.name AS artist_name',
            'COUNT(SongViews.id) AS views'
        ),
        'group' => array('ArtistsSong.song_id'),
        'recursive' =>  0,
        'limit' =>  20,
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'tbl_artists_songs',
                'alias' => 'ArtistsSong',
                'conditions'=> array('Song.id = ArtistsSong.song_id')
            ),array(
                'table' => 'tbl_artists',
                'alias' => 'Artist',
                'conditions'=> array('Artist.id = ArtistsSong.artist_id')
            ),array(
                'table' => 'tbl_song_views',
                'alias' => 'SongViews',
                'type' => 'left',
                'conditions'=> array('SongViews.song_id = ArtistsSong.song_id')
            ),
        ),
        'order' => array('Artist.name'=>'asc')

    );
```

Comment: ... come out of what? Provide some code and explain better what you want, please, is difficult to help with a two-line "question"

Comment: I have added sample code. check it. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

It is a bug in CakePHP.

However, there is a trick to do it.

You should add a virtual field in your primary model.

Assuming your primary model is Song, you should add this before calling paginate:

```
$this->Song->virtualFields = array(
    'artist_name' => 'Artist.name'
);
```

And now, you can sort by `artist_name`.

Comment: You can not use virtual field for sorting.. Read CakePHP Manual - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields

Comment: it works fine to use with order by field. which is a help in my case

Comment: this was a lifesaver and worked flawlessly for sorting & pagination, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked nearly 5 years ago, but I came across the same problem in CakePHP 3. I realised I needed to whitelist the field to allow for sorting:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    ...
    'sortWhitelist' => array ('Artist.name')
);
```

The Paginator automatically whitelists fields from the original table but not from the JOINed tables.

Comment: sortWhiteList should be written as sortWhitelist, -- lower case 'l' -- copied that from you and took us two hours to figure out what was wrong

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the answer, not sure how it snuck in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->paginate = ['fields' => ['id', 'name', 'company_id'],
                'contain' => [
                            'Companies' =>
                                 [
                                    'fields' => ['id', 'name'],
                                     'sort'=>['name'=>'ASC']
                                 ]
                'limit' => 10,

            ];
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by columns in associated models requires setting `sortWhitelist`.

```
$this->paginate['order'] = [ 'Artist.name' => 'desc' ];
$this->paginate['sortWhitelist'] = ['Artist.name', 'Song.title'];
$this->paginate['limit'] = $this->paginate['maxLimit'] = 200;
```

In HTML you have to set below line in table header:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Song.title', __('Title')) ?>
```